# Minimal ball enclosing a given polytope

Tags: optimization, polytopes

If I have a polytope (e.g. the feasible set of some $Ax \leq b$ where the result is closed), do there exist efficient algorithms for finding the minimum enclosing ball in $d$ dimensions? In other words, solving for:
$$
\min_{c \in \mathcal{R}^d, r \geq 0} r\\
s.t.\\
||x - c||_p \leq r,\ \forall x \in \mathcal{R}^d: Ax \leq b
$$
Any $p$ would be fine here, of obvious interest are: $p=1$, $p=2$, or $p=\infty$.

Of course, one can represent this is a minimax problem:
$$
r = \min_{c \in \mathcal{R}^d} \max_{x \in \mathcal{R}^d: Ax \leq b} ||x - c||_p
$$

Note that I don't have the vertices of the polytope, only $A$ and $b$.

Comment: Keep your first formulation and express your norm constraint as a conic one: https://github.com/MOSEK/Tutorials/blob/master/Fusion/minimum%20ellipsoid.ipynb

Comment: @AndreaCassioli How does writing it in conic form help, with respect to *all* feasible x? If there is an alternative representation which is tractable, please share it in an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I took the wrong link in my bookmarks... look at http://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/sdo.html#minimal-enclosing-ellipsoid

Comment: Still not the problem asked for. You're showing the simple cases of maximal ball when polytope in H-representation, and minimal ball when polytope in V-representation. The question is about minimal ball when in H-representation.

Comment: @AndreaCassioli - see what Johan wrote, he's correct, looking for minimal ball in H-representation (or barring that an approximation thereof)

Answer (score 4):

No, nothing efficient in H-representation. As you already seem to know, with vertices it is simple, but the step of going from half-plane representation to vertices might be intractable.

EDIT: $p = \infty$ is tractable, as you can address that case using duality in a polynomially sized linear program.

EDIT2: No reason to complicate matters when $p=\infty$. It simply corresponds to a weak bounding box of the polytope, which can be computed by solving $2d$ linear programs.

[image]